# Scrollable div mobile IE10 and -ms-viewport

Tags: html, css, mobile, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10

When using `-ms-viewport` in `CSS` then `scrollabe div` (overflow scrollable) cannot be scrolled anymore.
Issue happens only in Windows 8 phone. Tablet seems to be ok.

Does anybody know a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the width to auto (like below) instead of device-width seems to solve the scrolling issue.

```
@-ms-viewport {
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I had to use pixels so it didn't work for me.

Comment: use `width: 100px auto;`